# Power BI Premium per user report sharing

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

What is the best power BI license to have Premium per user or Premium capacity?

If I have premium per user do my report consumers also need premium per user license to access the report in powerbi.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your users, Premium Per User (PPU) can consume reports shared with other PPU's but not Pro accounts. Pro can share with Pro and PPU. PPU is designed to  have some of the features of capacity based Pro users, but not with the cost of Premium Capacity. Capacity is mainly for large number of users to be able to be read only, using the free license as a viewer. You still need Pro to create content.

I would recommend [PPU FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-per-user-faq) as a start for considerations.